# Google maps inside colorbox renders partiality gray area after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I use google Maps Api v3 to render google map inside colorbox using ajax call.

This is div that i use as container for map and some other things, and that one will be displayed in colorbox, also anchor on witch click ajax will be called:

```
<div id="cb-js-map-content" style="display: none"></div>
<a href="#cb-js-map-content" id="cb-js-showMap">
   Show Map
</a>
```

I use ajax to retrieve document in witch is map markup and js function that will generate map. This is ajax call and colorbox init:

```
FSM.mapAjaxCall = {
            GetMap: function () {
                $("#cb-js-showMap").click(function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: //my ajax url
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            var target = $("#cb-js-map-content");
                            target.append(data.Html);
                            if (typeof (data.Javascript) === "undefined") {
                                return;
                            }
                            $.loadScript(data.Javascript);
                        }
                    });
                     $("#cb-js-map-content").show();

                    $("#cb-js-showMap").colorbox({
                        inline: true,
                        height: colorboxHeight,
                        width: colorboxWidth,
                        onClosed: function () {
                           $("#cb-js-map-content").hide();
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
        };
```

This is div where map will be loaded

```
<div class="inlineClass" id="cb-js-mainMap" style="width:1023px; height: 800px; display:block"></div>
```

using this js function:

```
initializeMap = function () {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: centerLatlng,
                    zoom: 8,
                    minZoom: 10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: false
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("cb-js-mainMap"), mapOptions);

                //Add event for zoom changed and store data for map center
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                   //listener code
                });
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

            }
```

Now my problem is that this setting works almost always on firefox, and sparsely in Chrome. This is how problematic screen looks like:
[image]

Closing colorbox popup sometimes resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the resize-event in the success-callback of `$.ajax()`

Comment: use a short delay before you trigger resize.

Comment: I found length of the ajax call in milliseconds and put it in setTimeOut, now works. 
But is still get little blink when map resizes, is there any other way. Anyway thank you for tips...